# PHP: best way of 'saving' or caching variables to use, edit and recache at a later date?

Tags: php, database, file, caching

my script requires me to make, 'save', use, edit, and re-save very complex variables every 24 hours (as the new data comes in every 24 hours) for a prolonged period of time, usually an year or so. I have an array which contains other arrays, objects, which further contains more arrays and objects thus its making it a very complex array. I was wondering what option is the most efficient option for this long term data. A sql database, or saving varibles in a php file which can be included in other scripts for use or php APC.

Comment: APC is out of the question, as your data would be lost as soon as apache is restarted.  You want a durable datastore -- one that writes data to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a NoSQL type of database for storing your complex data structures, as you would not then need to have a well-defined schema that you break them into.  Alternateively if your data structure is safe for PHP serialization, you could store it in an SQL database keyed by date.  Another suggestion might be to use memcached or similar.

If storing in a filesystem if appropriate for your case, I have oftentimes stored data structures in JSON-encoded files as well.

Comment: Files are especially accessible for long time data-housing, e.g. in numbered folders contain year, month, day or similar.

Comment: what do you think about using var_export() to export data into a php file which can then be included in other scripts? Would this be efficient?

Comment: This wouldnot be efficient IMO, as var_export is not an easily readable format for PHP when trying to read the data back in.  If you want to go down this route, look at serialize() function

Comment: memcached would be inappropriate -- looks like he's aiming to store data for periods of months.  memcache offers no durability whatsoever.

Comment: yep, data would be stored for over 400 days